# Small Area Estimation techniques when no micro information is available

Tags: estimation, predictive-models, survey, survey-sampling, small-area-estimation

**Small area estimation (SAE)** techniques combine information from household surveys with existing auxiliary information at population level to make inferences of certain indicators for population groups who represent disaggregations for which the survey was not designed.

Most SAE methods, both direct and indirect (for more info read [this document](https://repositorio.cepal.org/bitstream/handle/11362/48107/3/S2200167_en.pdf)), require the survey to **record the small area where each respondent lives**. In other words, when trying to estimate a variable $y$ for each respondent $r$ in a small region $s$, most methods rely on the knowledge of $y_{rs}$.

I am studying a survey that does not provide $y_{rs}$, and only aggregated zoning information is provided for each respondent. According to [this Eurostat study](https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/documents/3859598/10167610/KS-GQ-19-011-EN-N.pdf/3b56be5d-8266-0ee7-7579-7c3e8e63289d), the only SAE methods that work for this case are called **synthetic estimators**, and basically consider the small areas to be homogeneus in that they have common parameters, without allowing any degree of heterogeneity between them.

As stated in [this other question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/599679/using-large-area-data-county-to-predict-small-area-estimand-census-tract/611819#611819), the assumptions of these methods are very strong and the bias of the estimation can be considerably high.

Are there any **other methods** that can be applied when no information regarding the target small area is covered within the survey?